# Set *args from variable?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, arguments

Is it possible to set `*args` from a variable?

```
def fn(x, *args):
    # ...

# pass arguments not as list but each as single argument
arguments = ??? # i.e.: ['a', 'b']


fn(1, arguments)

# should be equivalent to
fn(1, 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: Have you tried your suggestions for yourself to see the results?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney of course! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use argument unpacking (also known as splatting):

```
fn(1, *arguments)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def fn(x, *args):
...     return args
...
>>> arguments = ['a', 'b']
>>> fn(1, *arguments)
('a', 'b')
>>>
```

Comment: Aaah! One have to use the asterik! Excellent, thank you.

Comment: The asterisk (aka, the splat) both packs AND unpacks the arguments, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
# pass arguments not as list but each as single argument
arguments = ??? # i.e.: ['a', 'b']
```

Then arguments should be assigned `arguments = ['a' ,'b']`. This is argument unpacking.